# How to customize bootstrap docs with my styles

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have been tasked with pulling down bootstraps documentation project so that we can use this as our in house component library with our styles. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/8fa0d3010112dca5dd6dd501173415856001ba8b/README.md#documentation

What I am trying to understand is how/where do I add all my sass files which will be overriding parts of bootstraps core styles. I have tried to find documentation on this but I am coming up short. The main goal is to show the components with our colors and styles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly but if you want to override the styles you can override the `_variable.scss` by importing your own custom styles before importing bootstrap library in your sass file and if you want to add additional styles you can import your styles after you imported bootstrap for example

```
@import 'bootstrap_override_vars';
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap_override_component';
```